# Pattern for naming CLS compatible alternative Properties

Tags: c#, .net, cls-compliant

If i have a property like this

```
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public uint Something { ... }
```

and want to write an alternative, i can not just write an overload as i would do for methods.
But how should i name it? Is there some general way in the .NET libs?

```
public long SomethingAlternative { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest `SomethingAsInt64` to explicitly indicate the behavioural difference.

Comment: Or maybe `Something64` like Process class has

Comment: Don't use language keywords (especially since the purpose of this is CLS compliance!)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do it the reverse way: make the complaint version "something" and the non-compliant as "SomethingUnsigned"

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

SomethingCompliant meaning that it is compliant?

Comment: Spoken as the consumer of an arbitrary class staring at an intellisense prompt: compliant with what?